# "cookbook" for converting from QuickCheck1 to QuickCheck2?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Is there a cookbook available for converting from QuickCheck1 to QuickCheck2?

As some examples, `defaultConfig` ([replaced by `Args`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116262/how-to-get-haskell-quickcheck-2-4-to-increase-tests)) and `trivial` were removed and [`CoArbitrary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.2/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:7) introduced.

I did read the [what's new in QuickCheck 2 (with single answer ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933283/whats-new-in-quickcheck-2).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the author(s) of QuickCheck2 have not provided Release Notes which are typically used to answer questions like yours.  Assuming (uh oh, we know what that means!) that the author(s) updated the API doc, you can compare it to the version you have, and the differences will give you your cookbook.  As a last resort, you could compare the source code, but that would probably show more differences than you care about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such document -- which is a shame!

There was however at least one partial changelist posted to a mailinglist: http://osdir.com/ml/lang.haskell.general/2006-11/msg00060.html

The list given there includes:

- Shrinks failing test cases.
- Supports testing monadic code.
- Handles exceptions gracefully.
- coarbitrary has moved to a separate class, to make it easier to write simple instances of Arbitrary.
- Type-level modifiers for changing test data generation (e.g. NonNegative).
- Magic function table printing.
- User-defined actions when properties fail.